# Sort Method of Range Class Failed - 2 keys VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort data based on an unknown range. 
When i try to sort based on 2 keys i get a Sort Method of Range Class failed

```
Option Explicit

Sub PostReview()

Dim tWb As ThisWorkbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Integer, LastCol As Integer
Dim I As Integer, j As Integer
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("TR Query")

'Sort by Portfolio & Audit Date
Worksheets("TR Query").Activate
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
 .Range("B1:B" & Lastrow).Copy
 .Range("N:N").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set rng = Worksheets("TR Query").Range("N2:N" & Lastrow)
        rng.Value = rng.Value

    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(Lastrow, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, LastCol))

        With rng2
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range("N1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Range("L1"), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
End With
```

i am hoping that the data is sorted first by column N from A to Z then sorted by column L from newest to oldest.

the error in my code is here:

```
With rng2
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range("N1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _ 'error happens here
                Key2:=.Range("L1"), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try changing `.Range("N1")` and `.Range("L1")` to `ws.Range("N1")` and `ws.Range("L1")`

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(Lastrow, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, LastCol))` - this is just the last row? Seems like you want `.Cells(1, 1)` or maybe `(2, 1)` if you are working with column B.

Comment: Also: `LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` - note the added periods.

Comment: Move `Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` within the `With` block and change to `Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` too.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad - this did not work, this is a nested with so it references the worksheet when the first with begins.